# I am not able to Insert data and then retrieve the data with ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, database, laravel

I want to submit the from and then update the table with the submitted data without refreshing the page.
This is the modal which includes the form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="clientModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Client</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="clientForm">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label" for="client">Client</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client" name="client" placeholder="XYZ Cabs" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label" for="person">Contact Person</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="person" name="person" placeholder="Zack">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label" for="address">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label" for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="403 000 0000" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-4">
                            <label class="form-label" for="country">Country</label>
                            <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control" required>
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose...</option>
                                <option value="USA">USA</option>
                                <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                                <option value="UK">UK</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label" for="province">Province</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="province" name="province" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-2">
                            <label class="form-label" for="city">City</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label" for="usd">Price in USD</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usd" name="usd">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label" for="cd">Price in Canadian Dollar</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cd" name="cd">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my ajax script to submit the form and then update the table.

```
<script>
    $("#clientForm").submit(function (e){
       e.preventDefault();

       let client = $("#client").val();
       let person = $("#person").val();
       let address = $("#address").val();
       let phone = $("#phone").val();
       let country = $("#country").val();
       let province = $("#province").val();
       let city = $("#city").val();
       let usd = $("#usd").val();
       let cd = $("#cd").val();
       let _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();

       $.ajax({
           url: "{{route('client.add')}}",
           type: "POST",
           data:{
               client:client,
               person:person,
               address:address,
               phone:phone,
               country:country,
               province:province,
               city:city,
               usd:usd,
               cd:cd,
               _token:_token
           },
           success:function(response)
           {
               if (response){
                   $("#clientTable tbody").prepend('<tr><td>'+response.client+'</td><td>'+response.person+'</td><td>'+response.address+'</td><td>'+response.phone+'</td><td>'+response.country+'</td><td>'+response.province+'</td><td>'+response.city+'</td><td>'+response.usd+'</td><td>'+response.cd+'</td></tr>');
                   $("#clientForm")[0].reset();
                   $("clientModal").modal('hide');
               }
           }
       })

    });
</script>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('/add-client','ClientController@addClient')->name('client.add');
```

This is my controller function:

```
public function addClient(Request $request)
{
    $clients = new Client();

    $clients->client = $request->input('client');
    $clients->person = $request->input('person');
    $clients->address = $request->input('address');
    $clients->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $clients->country = $request->input('country');
    $clients->province = $request->input('province');
    $clients->city = $request->input('city');
    $clients->usd = $request->input('usd');
    $clients->cd = $request->input('cd');

    $clients->save();
    return response()->json($clients);
}
```

When i click Submit button nothing happens. Can anyone help me if i am missing anything or doing anything wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say nothing happens, have you checked the browser developer tools console to see if there are errors? or even if the request is sent

Comment: Error is:
POST http://localhost:8000/add-client 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: so the error is on the server code (and the request IS being made, so something IS happening) - can you see a server log, or does the server happen to send a description of the error back to the client? (`error: function(err)` callback in the request could help there)

Comment: by the way, there doesn't seem to be one of these `$("input[name=_token]")` in your markup

Comment: i have inserted the name token submit function "let _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();" and then i have in data:{_token:_token}

Comment: right, anyway, back to your error - internal server error - there should be some sort of log file on the server with, hopefully, an explanation of what the error is

Comment: i am not exactly sure what you are asking me to do. But when i click on internal serval error it show this:  send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ clients:342
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: if you want to me check anything else please brief me a little and i will check it. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: check the (PHP?) logs on the server as it's a internal server error - or if there's any response text ... use `error:` handler in your ajax (I've said this all before)

Comment: Sorry i am new to ajax and i didn't know how to use error handle. So after a little search i used error handler and i found the error in web.php file. Thankyou soo much for your help.